# Multiple select statements in xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I'm trying to use to select queries in bcp in xp_cmdshell and getting the result to a .csv file. I'm getting the result of the first query only in the select file. The first query has the total of all the rows in the table and that is the first row of the csv file and the remaining data in the .csv file is from the table. it is something like this

```
select count(col1),sum(col2)
from [Database1].[DBO].[Table1];
SELECT *
FROM [Database1].[DBO].[Table1]
```

Comment: Seems to me that combining these two queries in to a single output will mean that your CSV file won't be "valid"...

Comment: Hi I've got the requirement like this. the CSV file has to be in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want but you can concatenate the result sets with UNION (or UNION ALL)

if col1 and col2 are numeric columns:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT COUNT(col1), SUM(col2) FROM [database].[schema].[table] UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2 FROM [database].[schema].[table]" queryout "C:\file.csv" -c -t, -T -Slocalhost'
```

otherwise you should cast COUNT(col1) or/and SUM(col2) as VARCHAR so that the union works.

Best would be if you have a View for the statement, then BCP is a bit shorter:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp [database].[schema].[view] out "C:\file.csv" -c -t, -T -Slocalhost'
```

**note**: file.csv must exist! at least as an empty file with csv ending.

**EDIT:** 
As you said in your commment the number of columns doesn't match - so i tried it with the following testdata:

```
create table dbo.testtable
(
    charcol VARCHAR(9),
    intcol INT,
    charcol2 VARCHAR(50),
    floatcol FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.testtable
VALUES  ('abcd',1,'a longer text',1.1235),
        ('efgh',1,'a longer longer text',1.1235),
        ('ijkl',1,'a bit more text',1.1235),
        ('mnop',1,'pfff anoying',1.1235),
        ('qrstuvw',1,'please weekend come soon',1.1235)
GO
```

Then i created a view which gets the data - notice: i cast NULL as the supposed value:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.testview
AS
SELECT  CAST(COUNT(charcol) AS varchar(9)) AS charcol, 
        CAST(SUM(intcol) AS int) AS intcol, 
        CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(50)) AS charcol2,
        CAST(NULL AS float) AS floatcol 
FROM    dbo.testtable
UNION ALL 
SELECT  charcol,
        intcol,
        charcol2,
        floatcol
FROM    dbo.testtable
```

And finally bcp out to csv:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp [mydb].[dbo].[testview] out "C:\file.csv" -c -t, -T -Slocalhost'
```

and it works! The only thing is that bcp gives you this message:
*Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Warning: BCP import with a format file will convert empty strings in delimited columns to NULL.*
but that shouldn't matter - it works!

Comment: Union all will not work as the number of columns are different. I tried passing the above columns as null but it still didn't work out. I tried putting the comments into a stored proc and it still didn't work out.